# What is a better approach to designing android app navigation ? modal popups or drawer layouts?

Tags: android, master-detail

I am working on an android app for the first time and my first prototype had modal popups. Most people say that modal popups are not a good design and that sliders / drawers should be used . To be more specific - a Master Detail layout.  Is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

A few excerpts from the Android design docs:

> **Use navigation drawers if:**
>
> - You don't want to give up the vertical screen real estate for a dedicated tab bar.
> - You have a large number of top-level views.
> - You want to provide direct access to screens on lower levels.
> - You want to provide quick navigation to views which don't have direct relationships between each other.
> - You have particularly deep navigation branches.

...

> **Dialogs**
>
> Dialogs prompt the user for decisions or additional information
>   required by the app to continue a task. Such requests can range from
>   simple Cancel/OK decisions to more complex layouts asking the user to
>   adjust settings or enter text.

It really depends on how you want your UX to play out. If your app needs a user decision or more information before proceeding with some task, a dialog is appropriate. If a particular screen is not part of a progression but is an entry point, you'd almost certainly want it on a navigation drawer.